# Can I reference a dll programatically in VB.net? Or change the Local Copy path for a dll reference?

Tags: vb.net, dll

Can I reference a dll programatically in VB.net? Or change the Local Copy path for a dll reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what type of DLL you are talking about. If it is COM then you can use late binding (CreateObject()). If it is .NET then you can use reflection: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837908